# Fetching records of employee hired in specfic month

Tags: sql, oracle11g

Fetching records of employee hired in specfic month,
i want to show records of employee who were hired in january

my query is

```
select ename,job from emp where hiredate in(to_date('JAN','MONTH'));
```

Comment: Though this question shows little effort I fail to see how it's too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather, it should work something like this:

```
SELECT ename, job
FROM emp
WHERE to_char(hiredate, 'MON') = 'FEB'
```

Hope this helps.
Information from [this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:1063934100346906822) page.